# Python - Sorting based on the Aging and Displaying data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnYq3.png)

From above table image how can i group by data frame column(Aging) by highest to lowest values and display the same as table with respective source id and ticket (comma separated in case of multiple values) from highest order in Python

Python code to achieve the result

df['Aging'].max() is giving only the single highest value and not the order in descending order

Comment: Post your attempt and where did you get stuck

Comment: df['Aging'].max() is giving only the single highest value and not the order in descending order

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Your description is not clear. "Group by" means making groups of rows that have the same value with respect to the column(s) used for grouping, then applying some function, aggregation, or transformation for each such group. Instead, you say "by highest to lowest", which suggests you don't want to group at all, but simply to sort. Is `df.sort_values(by='Aging', ascending=False)` what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` and then `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your file')
df = df.groupby('Source').max().sort_values('Aging', ascending=False)
```

If this is not your expected output, then can you show what it should look like? Thanks in advance.